# validation of flow field

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, regular-expressions

I have a flow field (phone_private) and I want to validate if this field only contain numbers. I tried
`REGEX({!phone_private}, "[0-9 ]+")` but the rule fires also if the field contain numbers. If I changed the rule to `NOT(REGEX({!phone_private}, "[0-9 ]+"))` the rule doesn't fire. What is wrong with the rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check if it contains non-numbers, so that's what you need to do. The rule should look like:

```
REGEX({!phone_private}, "[^0-9 ]+")
```

The `^` operator at the beginning of a character class inverts the character matching, so only 0 through 9, and space, would be allowed.